# Why will an object literal load when in declared in external source file but not when called in a file including an external javascript file file

Tags: javascript, oop

The code in the external file is

```
var testing = {
    bugtest: function() {
        alert('No Bugs Here');
    }
}
```

In the php file I am using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="externalScript.js">
    testing.bugtest();
</script>
```

But this will not work why?

if I call the function in the external fil it works

```
var testing = {
    bugtest: function() {
        alert('No Bugs Here');
    }
}
testing.bugtest()
```

this will work but this not what I want it to do I want to be able to call the function in the main file? What would the cause of this problem be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use `src` attribute *and* the text node with `script` elements.

They must be exclusive, e.g. an element each.

So your HTML would look something like...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="externalScript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    testing.bugtest();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="externalScript.js">
testing.bugtest();
</script>
```

is wrong. You can *either* specify a src, or run inline code.